# Scala and Velocity Templates

Tags: scala, sbt, velocity, avro

I need to customize the location of a VM templates. I´m using a plugin called "sbt avro" to generate Java classes based in an Avro Schema. Can I point my custom template directory in build.sbt? Thanks!